# How to pull value from a form and paste on the site using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a form that allows for people to give reviews. They have to enter their name, email, and review in the input forms. I want to take that information and post it onto the site sidebar. Whenever I try, all I get is "object Object" in the sidebar, never what was place inside the input form. I have four questions

1. How do I pull the value from the form inputs and place them on the sidebar?
2. How do I place the new review under the review before?
3. How do I add the style to the review?
4. How do I empty the input forms after the review has been submitted?

[JFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/u4GmS/)

HTML:
    
          Our Reviews

```
      <ul class="review-list" id="sidebar-review-list">
        <li class="review">
          <p>
            Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet. Lemon drops topping carrot cake. Jujubes pudding chocolate
            cookie I love marshmallow I love toffee.
          </p>

          <a href="mailto:fakeemail@fakedomain.com">Jon Smith</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <form id="review-form" class="pure-form">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="pure-control-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="pure-input-1" id="name" placeholder="Name">
          </div>

          <div class="pure-control-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="pure-input-1" id="email" placeholder="Email">
          </div>

          <div class="pure-control-group">
            <textarea name="review" class="pure-input-1" id="review" placeholder="Review"></textarea>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" id="submit-review">Submit Review</button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.pure-control-group {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .reviews {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .review-list {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .review {
      background: #4faac9;
      padding: 1px 10px 10px;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 6px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .review a {
      color: #176075;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

JQUERY:

```
;(function($) {
    var $sidebar_review_list = $("#sidebar-review-list");
    var $review_form = $("#review-form");
    var $name = $("a");
    var $email = $("href");
    var $review = $("p");

    //get a reference to the submit buttons
    var $submit_review = $('#submit-review');

    var $sidebar_review_list = $('#sidebar-review-list');

    //function that will create the reviews
    var submit_review = function() {
        var $li = $('<li>');
        var $p = $('<p>');
        var $a = $('<a>');

        //set the value
        $p.text($review);
        $a.text($name);
        $a.attr('href', $email);

        $li.append($p);
        $li.append($a);

        $sidebar_review_list.append($li);
    };

    // add an event listener on the click event of the submit button
    $('#submit-review').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        submit_review();
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: i can't find a sidebar in tat fiddle.. am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

- You haven't selected jQuery framework in the fiddle, so nothing works.
- `$p.text($review); // invalid`
- For selecting an element with id `review` use `$('#review');`
- After fixing this, `$p.text($('#review'));` will set the whole jQuery
  object of `#review` element as `p`'s text, hence you get [object object]..
- For selecting the value inside it the `#review` element, use `$('#review').val();`

  so the above line in proper syntax would be `$p.text($('#review').val());`

  same in the case of rest of the code.

  1) As mentioned above use `val()` function to select the value

  2) Since you are appending new review to the same container that holds previous review, it automatically comes below the previous review in normal flow.

  3) For adding style you can use `.css()` function or for adding a css class `addClass()` function.

  4) you can use `reset()` function to manually clear the form after submission.

  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/u4GmS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of the form like this:

```
var form = $('#review-form');
form.each(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('name') + ' = ' + $(this).val());
});
```